# When I open an html file from MacOS Finder, why is chrome only opening a blank window/tab?

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome

I am having trouble getting Chrome to open html files from MacOS Finder. This includes double-clicking or right clicking and selecting open. These actions result in opening or making Chrome the active application, but not opening the html file. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? It didn't start after an update or any detectible change in how I work. It seems totally random.

Here's what I've tried:

- opening multiple html files created in different applications (sublime, dreamweaver, atom, etc.)
- deleting Chrome preferences
- resetting all Chrome settings
- running all possible updates
- restarting Chrome and computer

Here's what does work:

- opening files from within Chrome via File>Open File
- opening a new tab or window in Chrome and dragging an html file into it
- opening html files in Firefox and Safari by all available methods without encountering the issue I'm experiencing with Chrome.

Thank you!

Comment: It's a strange issue. Is your file empty? what version of chrome and macOS are you running? I'm on chrome 70 and macOS 10.13.5 and I don't have this problem

Comment: Chrome 70.0.3538.102 on High Sierra 10.13.6. I think this has to do with Sublime Text. I installed a package to open files from there directly in Chrome. I just tested creating an html file in text edit and it opened using double click from finder normally. Seems like now Sublime text is doing something funny with my files. I'll post again if I figure it out, but if anyone else knows already please share!

Answer (score 0):

Recreating the Sublime Text preference file resolved the issue. 
Admittedly I feel kinda dumb for not doing this in my first round of troubleshooting, but at least I did it now! Hopefully this at least helps some other people out there with the same issue.